# Android different languages on concurrent threads

Tags: android-resources, multiple-languages

In an Android app I am trying to use different languages at the same time on concurrent threads. One thread is the main UI thread, the other is a background email process sending emails to users in various languages. The problem is when I change the language on one thread it changes the language on the other thread and I get 'language leaks'.  Here is the method used to change the language to use the correct resources:

public static Resources getResourcesByLocale(Locale locale, Context context) {

```
    Resources res = context.getResources();
    AssetManager am = res.getAssets();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration mainConfig = res.getConfiguration();
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.setTo(mainConfig);
    config.locale = locale;

    return new Resources(am, dm, config);
}
```

This method changes the system wide configuration. So any other process using the configuration will inherit the resources determined by the locale. Is there a way to use multiple configurations one for each locale?  I have looked exhaustively for a solution other than calling this method everytime we display text.  We want to use this app in Europe and Middle East with about 27 languages.
Any help would be much appreciated.